# Loading data in one tab, viewing it another but the table won't reload

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, reload

I have a tab controller with 4 tabs in it. In the 2nd tab I am entering data and saving that data to a plist. In the 4th tab I am reading the plist back, making an array of one of the dictionary items (company names) and displaying them in a table. I am doing this in the viewDidLoad method.

This works fine for existing data. However, when I add data in the 2nd tab and then go to the 4th tab I can't figure out how to get the table to reload the data...I've tried [table reloadData] in the viewDidAppear method, no luck. Also tried to have a button to reload the data but nothing.

Could someone point me in the right direction on this?

Here's some code:

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//We need to implement the view controllers within the tab controller and make the tab controller the root controller of our app - note we are only using view 1-4 at first.

FirstViewController *fistView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
ThirdViewController *thirdView = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
FourthViewController *fourthView = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];

NSArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fistView, secondView, thirdView, fourthView, nil];

self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabController setViewControllers:viewControllersArray animated:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;

//end custom code

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

in my FourthViewController.h:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    //add our own image to the tab bar
    self.title = @"Results";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnResults.png"];
}
return self;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    newFileManager = [FileManager new];

    NSMutableDictionary* surveyResults = [newFileManager readPlist];

    NSMutableArray* tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSString* thisCompanyName in surveyResults) { 

    [tempArray addObject:thisCompanyName];
}

companyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];
NSArray* sortedCompanyNames = [companyNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

self.companyNamesTable = sortedCompanyNames;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to post more code to be sure but I would say you are not initializing the 4th tab everytime.  Meaning you code is something like this.

init{
[tab4 init]
}

callview{
[pushView tab4]
}

where as if you did

init{
}

callview{
[tab4 init]
[pushView tab4]
}

(meaning dont init the 4tab till your going to use it)

it should query the plist fresh, without any prior query results in the way

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I kind of do and don't get what you're saying, I posted some code above to show how I am adding the tabs view controllers and getting data into the table.